# How to get the gif which copied from safari from UIPasteboard

Tags: ios, iphone, uipasteboard

I am trying to get the copied gif from UIPasteboard, but what's the pasteboard type going to be? The com.compuserve.gif or kUTTypeGIF. Should I use 
- valueForPasteboardType: or just use image property to get the gif?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().setData(myGifData as! NSData, forPasteboardType:"com.compuserve.gif")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the proper way to store images in pasteboard is as NSData.Then reconstruct UIImage from NSData.